# AddPage in tcpdf not working

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I have html, when I run that html it is working well. But, when I want to create pdf of that html, design changes and I am not getting what design I have.
Also I can not add pages, my design has two page and I want the pdf to be in two pages.
here is my sample code:

```
require_once('eng.php');
require_once('tcpdf.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    // set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('RoyalHome.ae');
    $pdf->SetTitle('Listing ');
    $pdf->SetSubject('PDF of Listings');
    $pdf->SetKeywords('Royalhome, PDF, listing');

    $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', 'B', 10);

    // add a page
    $pdf->AddPage();
```

my html is here  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/suzsu/)

```
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->SetFillColor(255,255,0);
$pdf->lastPage();
$sr =  $fileName . '.pdf';
$pdf->Output($sr, 'D');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tested your code. Ran into the following issues:

1. You have relative URLs for img tags, which, on my machine, results in tcpdf throwing an error when trying to fetch the images.  Make sure you use absolute URLs to avoid this.
2. You are using the `D` flag for Output destination.  I got errors because headers were already sent. If you are generating and outputting the pdf after the page loads, or if errors are thrown and output to screen, the output will fail.

I removed all `<img />` elements and changed the destination flag to `F` and the pdf generated just fine on my desktop.